# Python & SciPy - use fsolve with COM connection

Tags: python, com, scipy

I am trying to use scipy Optimize `fsolve` function to find the zero of a function defined using a COM object.

First, I create the COM object:

```
import win32com.client
os = win32com.client.Dispatch("PX32.OpenServer.1")
```

This COM object works as an interface to a program where I input variables, then make calculations, and obtain results, using the `setvalue`, `docommand` and `getvalue` methods/functions.

If I define a function like:

```
def fn(x):
    os.setvalue("INPUT_VAR_STRING", x)
    os.docommand("COMMAND_STRING")
    return float(os.getvalue("RESULT_STRING"))
```

By changing the input value (passed into `fn` through `x`), I get different output values:

```
fn(100)
> 18.139818203
fn(190)
> -40.93182830
```

But, if I try to use `fsolve` to find the root of the `fn` function, I get an error:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
fsolve(fn,150)
> TypeError
> (...)
> TypeError: Internal error - the buffer length is not the sequence length!
```

What does this mean? How can I try to solve this error that has appeared?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. According to http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/pycse/pycse.html,

> 12.11 Using an external solver with Aspen
> (...)
>
> `flashT = float(flashT) # COM objects do not understand numpy types`

That was the main thing. I had to change

`os.setvalue("INPUT_VAR_STRING", x)` for

`os.setvalue("INPUT_VAR_STRING", float(x))` to get the expected results.